# composer.phar and (different) PHP versions of working environments

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm having the following problem - my dev environment has PHP 5.4.7, while pagodabox has only 5.3.10. Whenever I deploy on pagodabox and the composer hook executes, it's a possibility that one or more dependencies will require PHP > 5.3.10.

Does this happen because of the lock file or something else? And, can I resolve this easily without manually specifying package versions (instead of "dev-master" which might require php 5.4.7, manually set the version to something like "1.2.1") ?

Basically I want to be able to specify something like: "install only packages that work with php 5.3.10 or older"

Is this possible?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to achieve this, but you could report it as an [issue on github](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues). It sounds like an interesting feature to have.

Comment: Thanks, I opened a feature request here https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1522